# Magento 2.1 : try to remove products images programmatically but got error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

Try to Remove Products Images but got error in magento2

**Error : "Product with SKU '12553' is not linked to product with SKU '12552'" in**

My code is:

```
$get_ids = array(12551,12552,12553,12554);

foreach($get_ids as $ids){
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($ids);
    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

    $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
        unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
    }
    $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
    $productRepository->save($product);
}
```

Comment: Please confirm whether the products belongs to simple ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productArray = array("2011", "2012", "2013");
//Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
foreach($productArray as $key=>$productId)
{    
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry)
{
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);

echo "Product Image has been deleted for".$productId."</br>";

}
echo "Yahooooo";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i want to remove through sku but i could not be delete
i just want to first read the file then remove product images accordingly csv file skus
anyone can help me for this solution**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

//Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
//skus
// $productArray = array("7750087","7750100");
$file = fopen('skus.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
$header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row
while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 40000, ",") ) {

    $data = array();
    $data = array_combine($header, $row);

    $productSkus=$data["sku"];

   foreach($productArray as $key=>$productSkus){

   $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')- 
>load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager- 
 >create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
 $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();

 foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry){
 unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
 }

$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);

echo "Product Image has been deleted for".$productSkus."</br>";

}
}
echo "Yahooooo";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions did not work for me. This one did, tested on M2.4.3.

```
private $gallery_rm
    
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $gallery_rm
) {
    $this->gallery_rm = $gallery_rm;
}

public function removeImagesFromProduct($product_object) {
    // get all images from product object
    $media_gallery_entries = $product_object->getMediaGalleryEntries();

    foreach($media_gallery_entries as $product_img) {
        $this->gallery_rm->deleteGallery($product_img->getId());
    }
}
```